# basic CSS label aligning

Tags: php, css, forms

Hi basically I am new to css etc so my form may be awful, however last night it was appearing abosloutely fine....I haven't touched it, and on loading the site this morning it is not appearing correctly.

so here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Zc6u/),

can somebody wise please explain why its changed over night? I am sure I haven't touched it.

thanks,

Comment: sorry ye should have mentioned that, no, I have been working with firefox and chrome, both displaying fine til today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add `clear: left` to:

```
#stylized label {
    clear: left;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 180px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/7Zc6u/5/

What's happening is the edge of the password label is getting caught on the edge of the username label.

Comment: Whoops, the link to the jsfiddle wasn't right; I had fixed it in Firebug but forgot to add it to the css in jsfiddle. :\

Comment: It allows an element to clear a floated element's dimensions. Read a great description from a pro: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: @buymypies - I can't tell you that, I can only give you the solution to how to fix is. :(

Answer (score 1):

replacing padding

`padding: 5px 3px 2px 12px;` to `#stylized label` solves the problem

Or use

`clear:left;` in `#stylized label`

Comment: this does work, but more so what I wanted to know is how it suddenly went from working to not working over night :S

Comment: Yeah, I've done that a few times. Sometimes it's just staring me in the face but I don't see it.